# SQL Server Read Only DataBases usage advantages & areas

Tags: sql-server

We can set our DataBase read-only, and it restricts some commands like Auto-Shrink, Auto Statistics, and DBCC commands. But it also gives a high performance with limiting that features. 
We can use

```
ALTER DATABASE dbName SET READ_ONLY
```

command to set DB read only. But, why we should use Read Only Databases? What are the advantages, and what are the usage areas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some times you may have a database which is shared by a publisher - historical data, stock data, statistics, studies.  Or potentially your own archived data.

It may or may not start as a SQL Server database, but the data is static.

You never want it to be altered by anyone at all, accidentally or intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

Databases that are read only?

For examlple lookup data that you buy that is regularly replaced but read only under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally use a read only filegroup not an entire read only database.

However, you may have a legacy database that no-one should update for example.